# Docker Machine で ~/.ssh/MY_KEY を正しく保存する方法

Tags: docker

`docker-machine create` コマンドで作成した VM に保存した `~/.ssh/my_id_rsa` ファイルが、VM の再起動時に消えてしまいます。ドキュメントを読んでもこの現象に該当する記述が見当たらず、どうしたものかと悩んでいます。

ホストマシンは Mac OS (El Capitan) で、docker-machine のバージョンは次の通りです。

```
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

また、VM は次のオプションで作成しました。

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
```

もし何か思い当たることがあれば、教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一日待って回答を得られなかったので、[本家](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232018/how-can-i-save-my-rsa-key-in-my-docker-machine)の方で質問してみました。

これによると、`boot2docker`は `/var/lib/boot2docker` ディレクトリにあるデータをのぞいて、起動時に `boot2docker.iso` の内容で初期化されるから次の二つの方法のいずれかで回避するといい、とのことでした。

- 鍵をホストの `/Users/any/path/you/want` に保存する (`/Users` は `boot2docker`でマウントされるから)
- 鍵を `/var/lib/boot2docker` に保存する